# "Return" out of Function, If Statement Inside Lodash forEach()

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
function(){
    _.forEach(listOfSomething, function (something) {
      if(someCondition){
        return false
      }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Looks simple enough - trying to check each item for some condition, if it isn't met for any item exit out of function and return false. When loop is done without exiting, return true.

Always returns true, tried console logging, and it does hit the "return false" point.

Am I missing something obvious about how js works or is this a lodash thing?

Comment: You have two functions here.  The "return false" inside of the forEach statement affects the inner function and not the outer function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you're missing is that your `return false` statement is inside a different function than your `return true` statement. You probably want to use a different lodash method like `any`/`some`.

```
function(){
    return _.some(listOfSomething, function (something) {
      return someCondition;
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah, the common sense things I somehow miss, Thanks, will accept answer when timer expires.

Comment: "Checks if predicate returns truthy for any element of collection. The function returns as soon as it finds a passing value and does not iterate over the entire collection." https://lodash.com/docs#some

Comment: Now, _.forEach() also breaks when returned false;

Answer (score 4):

Thats because there are 2 functions, the return of the second function won't make the first function return. You should set a variable as true and change it to false if the condition is met:

```
function(){
    var condition = true;
    _.forEach(listOfSomething, function (something) {
      if(someCondition){
        condition = false;
        return;
      }
    });
    return condition;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess I did miss the fact that forEach() is a method of "_" object here. Noobs gonna noob.

Comment: the thing is that you'd also want to break from the loop from what I understand and I'm not sure if return false that you were doing does break the forEach (have to check its docs)

Comment: I do want to break out of the loop, but it doesn't seem that lodash supports  any sort of "break" statements in forEach (or javascript in for loops, only in switch statements).

Comment: And they don't provide a goto either #LOL (guess you've already found the solution with \_.some)

Comment: The "return;" you added here works like a "continue;" in a regular loop, hence completely wrong in this case, it has absolutely no effect on the length of your loop. You should use "return false;" instead.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at it, the "return" will just return false from the inner function that is executed once for every element of the list (via the forEach), not exit the outer function

In fact, I think the forEach will keep on executing (not sure about its semantics, maybe it looks for a "false" result from the function it calls to break the loop)

but set a variable called result before the forEach to true and in the if set it to false, then at the end have a return result

that should work, but you should check the docs about that forEach to see if indeed doing a "return false" will break the loop, or if there's some break or similar command to do it (maybe _.break(); but I'm not sure what that "_" instance is)

Comment: "_" is just lodash, a library like underscore js that provides methods for working with arrays.

Comment: thanks for the tip, hadn't heard of it before. Indeed as other answer points, \_.some should do the trick.